# Can a web service return DefaultListModel?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a Java web services deployed on Glassfish server using Netbeans. Service fetches data from database and populates DefaultListModel **customers**.

DefaultListModel **customers** is returned to program and used to populate JList however I get error bellow. The name of the web service main package is **bank**. Can I actually return DefaultListModel from web service and is there any way to repair this error.

```
incompatible types
found   : bank.DefaultListModel
required: javax.swing.DefaultListModel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different classes that happen to have the same short name. That doesn't make them interchangeable.

Your service layer should not depend on the technology you have chosen for the GUI layer. A DefaultListModel won't be very useful when you'll switch to a webapp to display the result of the service. Make it return a `List<Customer>`. `DefaultListModel` is nothing more than a wrapper around a list anyway.

Comment: I agree. Using a standard List is the way to go. Just build a new list based on a DefaultListModel after getting the list data back from the web service.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am not sure how should I initialize  List<customers>.

private List<E> customers;?